# Cannot create MediaPlayer inside thread

Tags: android, android-service, android-mediaplayer

I have a Service that starts a thread, where I need to create a MediaPlayer:

Inside `onStartCommand` I call the main function that runs a thread.

```
public int onStartCommand(Context context, Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    Log.e(TAG, "onStartCommand");

    doTask(context);
    return START_STICKY;
}


void doTask(Context context) {

    isActive = true;
    thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                threadLoop(context);
            } 
            catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });

    thread.start();
    Log.e(TAG, "Thread started");
}
```

After this, inside `threadLoop` I am trying to create a MediaPlayer

```
MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(context, AudioData);
```

but I can't do anything with the 1st *context* parameter. I tried to send context and get the base one, but it doesn't work.

Maybe I should use another service for MediaPlayer?

Thank you in advance

**Update**

Error:
`Cannot resolve method 'create(android.content.Context, short[])'`.

Comment: Try using `threadLoop(ServiceName.this)`.  What's the error that you are getting?

Comment: @RoshanaPitigala thank you, I've edited the question and tried to add `MyService.this`. Still doesn't work.

Comment: Well, the error is clear. `MediaPlayer` don't have a method that takes a `short[]`. What is this `AudioData`? What are you trying to do?

Comment: I am trying to play a generated sound wave. I suppose I should try AudioTrack.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're passing in the wrong data to the second parameter.  The first parameter is fine.  The second is a resource id or a Uri, not a short[].  If the short array is supposed to be audio data (like the raw .wav data), write it to a file and pass it the URI of that file.

Also, passing context to a Thread like that is dangerous and can lead to memory leaks.  You need to make sure the thread is ended when the service is ended to prevent it.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I'll try AudioTrack then.

Comment: An audio track isn't going to work either.  It needs to be a resource id or a Uri.  The various create calls are documented at https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer#create(android.content.Context,%20android.net.Uri,%20android.view.SurfaceHolder,%20android.media.AudioAttributes,%20int)

Comment: I got it. I should use MediaPlayer if I work with saved audio or URI. Here I am trying to play a generated sound wave. I suppose AudioTrack is what I need.

Answer (score 0):

Your code should be like this

```
MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, uri);
```